# Is it possible to evaluate any unknown in an equation?

Tags: problem-solving

E.g., I have this function
$P = e^{-x} \frac{x^k}{k!}$
and I can't figure out how to evaluate $x$ If it's possible, please show me how. And if it's possible, is it possible with any equation?

Comment: This equation gives you the probability of observing k independent events per given time period, if the average in that time period is x. So, what you can do is measure the number of events in a very long time period and then calculate the average number in that given time period.

Comment: It is not possible with all equations.  In particular polynomials and exponentials do not play nicely together, so equations that mix them are often not soluble analytically.  Sometimes the Lambert W function can help, but it doesn't leave me feeling enlightened as I know very little about its properties.  You can often solve them numerically, but that may not help further on.